# Understanding the Level set Equation

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry

I have a question about the central equation of the Level Set method (e.g. [https://math.berkeley.edu/~sethian/2006/Semiconductors/ieee_level_set_explain_technical.html](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Esethian/2006/Semiconductors/ieee_level_set_explain_technical.html), or [Derivation of Basic Level Set Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22489/derivation-of-basic-level-set-equations)).

We are given a function $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now we consider the trajectory of a particle on the level set at height 0 over time. So let $C_{t}:= \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n | \Phi(\mathbf{x},t) = 0 \}$ for $t \geq 0$. We consider a trajectory $\gamma: [0,\infty), t \mapsto p_{t}$ with $p_{t} \in C_{t}$.

Now let $\mathbf{s}(t) := (\gamma(t),t)^{\intercal}$ be the evolution of a point on the contour together with the time.

If we compute the derivative of $\Phi$ with respect to time $t$, we obtain by the chain rule:

$\frac{\partial \Phi \circ \mathbf{s}}{\partial t}(t)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_{i}}(\mathbf{s}(t))\frac{\partial \mathbf{s}_{i}}{\partial t}(t) + \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}(\mathbf{s}(t)) \frac{\partial \mathbf{s}_{n+1}}{\partial t}(t)$, where $s_{n+1}(t) = t$ and $s_{i}(t) = \langle \gamma(t),e_{i} \rangle$ and $e_{i}$ is the $i$-th canonical basis vector for $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

So for n=2,
$\frac{\Phi \circ \mathbf{s}}{\partial t}(t)= \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x}(\mathbf{s}(t))\frac{\partial \mathbf{s}_{1}}{\partial t}(t)+\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}(\mathbf{s}(t))\frac{\partial \mathbf{s}_{2}}{\partial t}(t) + \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}(\mathbf{s}(t)) \frac{\partial \mathbf{s}_{3}}{\partial t}(t)$ and $s_{3}(t) = t$.

We can simplify this as:
$\frac{\partial \Phi \circ \mathbf{s}}{\partial t}(t)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_{i}}(\mathbf{s}(t))\frac{\partial \mathbf{s}_{i}}{\partial t}(t) + \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}(\mathbf{s}(t)) $.

Now by construction $\Phi \circ \mathbf{s}$ is the 0 function, thus
$0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_{i}}(\mathbf{s}(t))\frac{\partial \mathbf{s}_{i}}{\partial t}(t) + \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}(\mathbf{s}(t)) $.

The equation is then used to obtain an update rule (see also [Derivation of Basic Level Set Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22489/derivation-of-basic-level-set-equations)), which tells how to change a point over time. Essentially,
$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}(\mathbf{s}(t))$ is approximated by $\frac{1}{\Delta t} [-\Phi(\mathbf{s}(t+\Delta t))+\Phi(\mathbf{s}(t))]$, which can be used to see how to compute $\Phi(\mathbf{s}(t+\Delta t))$ given $\Phi(\mathbf{s}(t))$ and the $0$-equation just derived.

However, this equation or update rule is applied to all points.
Since the entire derivations assumes that we start with a point $p \in C_{0}$ on the contour, and use a trajectory of points that stay on the contour (so using a trajectory $\gamma$),  I dont understand why the update rule can be  applied to all points (e.g. of an image).

So in short,
instead of
$\Phi(\mathbf{s}(t+\Delta t)) := \Delta t [\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_{i}}(\mathbf{s}(t))\frac{\partial \mathbf{s}_{i}}{\partial t}(t)] + \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}(\mathbf{s}(t)) $, I understand that the method is using
$\Phi(\mathbf{x}, t+\Delta t) := \Delta t [\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_{i}}(\mathbf{x}, t)\frac{\partial \mathbf{s}_{i}}{\partial t}(t)] + \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}(\mathbf{x}, t) $, for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

For example, have a look at https://profs.etsmtl.ca/hlombaert/levelset/ .In the paragraph "Level set equation" the equation I wrote down is shown. In the subsequent paragraph "Implementation" you see that the equation is applied to all pixels.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by applying it to all points. I'll take a look at the reference in the morning.

Comment: If you have a look at https://profs.etsmtl.ca/hlombaert/levelset/ you see in the paragraph "Level set equation" the equation I wrote down. In the subsequent paragraph "Implementation" you see that the equation is applied to all pixels.

Comment: @user20672 I updated the text with a a more detailed question.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after reading the references, I'll offer my own interpretation.

Every pixel belongs to the domain of $\Phi(x,t)$; it is a globally defined function. Therefore, if we denote the image of all pixels by $\Phi_t(X) = U_t \subset \mathbb{R}$, the preimage $\Phi^{-1}_t(U_t)$ is a partition of $X$. Put more simply, every $(x,t) \in X \times [0,\infty)$ belongs to a contour $\mathbf{x}_c(t)$ at each time $t$ for some constant $c$.

However, we allow $\Phi(x,t)$ to take on *any* value outside of the zero-contour $\mathbf{x}_0(t)$. So long as it correctly predicts $\mathbf{x}_0(t)$, we don't care how it behaves elsewhere. Thus, you apply the update knowing that it will approximate the true solution on the zero-contour for all $x(t) \in \mathbf{x}_0(t)$, and will only generate a solution that is globally *consistent* with the $\mathbf{x}_0(t)$ for which you solved.

I believe this is what the author meant in the link that you provided when they said:

> The question still remains: what is the function $\phi(\mathbf{x}(t),t)$? It can actually be anything we want as long as its zero
> level set gives us the contour.

Comment: So basically you mean its just one way to extend the formula to the entire space, but in principle, outside of the zero contour points, another update rule could have been used ?

Comment: There are an infinite number of functions that will have the same zero-contour $\mathbf{x}_0(t)$. This is sound derivation for an approximation of one such function, yes. I've updated the answer to be clearer for anyone else that might be curious.